# What is the fastest way to read String from file?

Tags: java, android, performance, optimization

What is the fastest way to read String from a random position in file? The file is located on  SD card, the code will run in Android.

What I'm currently doing – I read the bytes into a byte array and pass it to the String constructor. The charset is UTF-8. About 90% of running time is spent in the String constructor, in which Charset.decode(...) is the bottleneck.

The Strings I'm reading are public transport stop names, so they are about 15 characters long on average.

**EDIT**: Tested in on Android 2.3.3 emulator and it's much faster than 2.1 (probably due to JIT compilator). Each String can be read in about 1ms which is fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

You've failed to mention how many bytes you're trying to read, how often you're creating a new string from read bytes or how long you script is taking to execute.

Post some code, show us what algorithms you're using to achieve what you're doing. To me, this sounds like a trivial optimization since you can't control the decode function without writing your own. If everything else is optimized, I'd say you're about as fast as you're going to get reading from file. So again, how many operations are we talking? How long is this trace taking?

Comment: I added additional info, I'll add more later.